# Epoch vs. Date and time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have simple question. 
Which format of time is better for storing in mysql, epoch or standard date-time (human readable format).
I want to know what format will be better later in table which stores millions of rows, regarding speed of select statements.

Comment: You should stored date/times as either `datetime` or `timestamp` fields.  Do *not* stored them as "human readable" character fields.  If you have to, store them in the format or "YYYY-MM-DD" or "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the unix epoch. I've done many extremely massive MySQL databases, one of which is a data tracking application that logs millions of records every day for some users.

The reasons `epoch` is better than `datetime`:

- `int` is only 4 bytes versus 8 for `datetime` - better for storage/memory and ultimately indexing/performance. When you're dealing with millions of rows, it really matters
- Most server-side languages need to convert from the string format to an int format anyway, before it can reformat the data
- No dependency on timezones - with `datetime` you need convert strings that are not stored with timezone ident but with the epoch you only need to know the timezone converting to

Comment: What about the year 2038 problem with 4 byte limitation?

Comment: Can we apply complex queries on epoch time? as we can do it with timestamps like date difference, greater than or less than dates, and IN queries?

Comment: Storing timestamp as epoch is generally a bad idea: refer [Epoch Mania](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/) and [Storing Date/Times in Databases](https://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html) for reasons.  **Summary**: storing date and time isn't as simple as using an integer/double as there're many other parameters (like time zone, leap years, etc.) involved.

Comment: [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) is another issue if you're using 4-byte integers as @Don mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a date as a string, that uses lots of space, MySQL is optimized to store dates from Unix timestamps "epochs" as a 10 digit number which uses just 4 bytes

The DateTime type uses 8 bytes so as far as speed would be slower than epochs, however you may want to consider that mySQL has 20 or 30 functions that work with the DATETIME type so depending on what you are doing you have to take into consideration the time it will take to convert.

Direct answer to your question is nothing is faster than epochs!

Answer (score 0):

First, forget TIMESTAMP. The 2k38 epochalypse is closer than you think.

Since there is other instant datatype, no timezone info in a DATETIME, we are no worse storing a BIGINT epochtimemillis than a UTC DATETIME, until they (the DB makers) figure a new "instant" data type to give us asap.

If you are going to merely record instants, a BIGINT epochimemillis is fine.
You can always do the date math in the app, but beware, you may be forced to do date math in the app! (I mean, really poor performance when you can't implement the WHERE clause you need).

I generally like to avoid the insanity of all the tiers fiddling with the timezone, Have you read the docs? It's utterly ridiculous. Java is changing, driver is changing, server is changing, pile of confusing properties to try to tell the driver and server what to do with timezones, with defaults changing too (like the 8.0.23 mess). The server is simply NOT enforcing that the client knows what it is storing.

It's no wonder why many devs simply run away from it all. This is why we want a new 64 bbits "instant" data type. I would gladly do a hefty migration if this means continued use of a "timestamp"-like that the driver would handle seemlessly for my unchanging code.

With a BIGINT, sorting and finding the age of something or time diff couldn't be easier. No explanation needed, just doing integer divisions by 60, 3600, 1440, 86400, whatever usual multiples you need.

With a BIGINT epoch time millis. date rendering is entirely a presentation issue, not storage. Many apis work with this, like stripe.

Doing date tests (group bys hours of day, where hour between 0 and 8, etc. ) may require a virtual column that gives you the UTC to do those fancy queries/aggregations. Whatever index you feel like having on the virtual column is just as good as on an actual datetime column. Particularly around DST shifts, it's not easy to deal with 23h or 25h days...

Hope this helps not being scared of using a BIGINT epoch time (millis).